# Almacenar un valor Date de Java en MySQL

Tags: java, jdbc

Estoy intentando almacenar en un registro de MySQL un valor `java.util.Date` que contenga una fecha y una hora de forma conjunta. He probado con esto:

```
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();  
plantilla = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm");
String tiempo = plantilla.format(d);
```

Y luego grabar en MySQL el valor `tiempo` pero no funciona. No sé si tengo que utilizar la clase `java.sql.Date`. En todo caso ando perdido.

¿Puedo grabar directamente a lo bruto un valor `java.util.Date` en MySQL definiendo el campo con otro tipo distinto a `DATETIME` o no es recomendable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer, si tu campo en la base de datos es un date, tenes que convertir de java.util.Date a java.sql.Date

```
java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
```

Entonces podes usar un preparedStatement y usar date2 para el insert

Comment: El tipo `java.sql.Date` almacena solo la fecha, se pierde la información de la hora.

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Puedo grabar directamente a lo bruto un valor java.util.Date en MySQL definiendo el campo con otro tipo distinto a DATETIME o no es recomendable?

JDBC no soporta el registro de instancias directas de `java.util.Date`. En su lugar, tienes tres clases en el paquete `java.sql` que extienden de `java.util.Date` para que puedas realizar la operación:

- [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). Este tipo solo almacena la fecha. Se pierde la información de la hora. Equivalente al tipo sql `DATE`.
- [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html). Este tipo solo almacena la hora. Se pierde la información de la fecha. Equivalente al tipo sql `TIME.
- [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). Este tipo almacena tanto fecha y hora. Equivalente al tipo sql `DATETIME` y `TIMESTAMP`, dependiendo del soporte que tenga el motor de base de datos.

Para tu caso, te recomiendo crear una instancia de `Timestamp` a partir de tu objeto `java.util.Date` así:

```
java.util.Date miObjetoJavaUtilDate = ...
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(miObjetoJavaUtilDate.getTime());
PreparedStatement pstmt = ...
//...
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
```

Y para obtener un objeto `java.util.Date` desde `Timestamp`:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = ...
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    Date miFechaYHora = new Date(rs.getTimestamp(1).getTime());
}
```

Puedes crear y obtener instancias de las otras clases `java.sql.Date` y `java.sql.Time` de manera similar.

Answer (score 0):

1.- El primer paso en tu base de datos es observar que el campo donde va a ir la fecha esté en formato `date` o `datetime` que es el que permite guardar las fechas.

2.- Deberás hacer una conversión dentro del programa. Esto es para asignar el valor:

```
try {
     String formato = comboFormato.getSelectedItem().toString();
     //Formato
     Date date = SelectorFecha.getDate();
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formato);
     txtFechaSeleccionada.setText(sdf.format(date));
} catch(NullPointerException ex) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "¡Al menos selecciona una fecha válida!", "¡Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

3.- Después deberás separar los campos para componer la fecha:

```
int año = SelectorFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mes = SelectorFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int dia = SelectorFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
txtDía.setText("" + dia);
txtMes.setText("" + mes);
txtAño.setText("" + año);
```

4.- Al final esto valores los concatenas y el resultado se lo das a tu variable tipo `date`

Anexo: http://blog.rolandopalermo.com/2009/12/capturando-fechas-de-un-jdatechooser.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Cliente {
    private String CODIGO_CLIENTE;  
    private int ESTATUS_CLIENTE ; 
    private String RUC;
    private String NOMBRE ; 
    private String DIRECCION ; 
    private String CIUDAD  ;
    private Date FECHA_INGRESO ;
    private int TIPO_CLIENTE ; 
    private  float LIMITE_CREDITO ; 
    private String CORREO_ELECTRONICO ; 
    private String TELEFONO ;

    public Cliente(){
        CODIGO_CLIENTE="";  
        ESTATUS_CLIENTE =0; 
        RUC="";
        NOMBRE="" ; 
        DIRECCION="" ; 
        CIUDAD ="" ; 

        FECHA_INGRESO=;quiero inicializarlo y no me sale no se is puedas ayudarme

        TIPO_CLIENTE = 0; 
        LIMITE_CREDITO =0; 
        CORREO_ELECTRONICO="" ; 
        TELEFONO ="";
```